# static sql WHERE into dynamic

Tags: database

I have this sql segment:

`WHERE MONTH(pd.field_publish_date_value) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND YEAR(pd.field_publish_date_value) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND fd.langcode='sk' AND fd.type='article'`

I need to transform it into something like this:

```
->condition(MONTH(pd.field_publish_date_value), MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '=')
->condition(YEAR(pd.field_publish_date_value), YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '=')
->condition(fd.langcode, 'sk', '=')
->condition(fd.type, 'article', '=');
```

but, how to interpret MONTH() and YEAR() functions in D8? Google offered me only Drupal 7 `->where()` - I need to make it with `->condition()`.

[EDIT]

```
$sqlSK = "SELECT COUNT(fd.nid)
    FROM node fd                                
    LEFT JOIN node__field_publish_date pd
    ON fd.nid=pd.entity_id
    WHERE MONTH(pd.field_publish_date_value) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND 
    YEAR(pd.field_publish_date_value) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND 
    fd.langcode='sk' AND fd.type='article'
";
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add some more information? I'd like to see all code that builds the query, not just the `->condition()` part. Also, tell us if you're using a MySQL database or something else. Finally: why do you think you must use `->condition()`? If I'm not mistaken, Drupal 8 also has a [where()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21ConditionInterface.php/function/ConditionInterface%3A%3Awhere/8.4.x) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `Connection` object (`\Drupal::service('database')` or `@database` with DI).

```
$database = \Drupal::service('database');
$database->select('node_field_data', 'fd');
$database->join('table','pd', 'pd.XXX=fd.XXX'); //trying to match your query
$database->where('MONTH(pd.field_publish_date_value = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)');
$database->condition('fd.langcode', 'sk')
$database->condition('fd.type', 'article');
$result = $database->execute();
//do something
$result->fetchAll();
```